# Argument of type <Interface> is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

Tags: angular, typescript

I just started out doing some typescripts in angular and came across a problem that I wish for some assistance of.

```
list = [];
interface a {
   s : string;
   n : number;
}

const b = {'asdf',1234} as a;
list.push(b)
```

But I keep receiving the error

```
Argument of type a is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

Any suggestions on what I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define in a class an array member like:

```
list = [];
```

List is going to be assigned by default the type `never[]`, what you need here is to assign a proper type for the array, something like:

```
list: a[] = [];
```

or

```
list: any[] = []; // If you don't care (not as good)
```

Probably you are defining in Angular your component like:

```
interface a {
   s : string;
   n : number;
}

class MyComponentFails {
  list = [];

  addToList() {
    const b = { s: 'asdf', n: 1234} as a;

    this.list.push(b) // Argument of type 'a' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  }
}
```

Which won't work, instead define it like this:

```
class MyComponentWorks {
  list: a[] = [];

  addToList() {
    const b = { s: 'asdf', n: 1234} as a;

    this.list.push(b) // Ok
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAjsg3gWAFDLwZ2QC5l8wpQBzAbhz2RGIYFcBbAI2luwF8ccEAGzj5CAWQCeAYQD2rAA4yQEcADE4wQYSy5kg4GWQBeZAG0AutzqoAJjYAqMgDIGwACgCUGa3gRLD7MYYpCQA5CI2MKEANAwkAIwATADMACw8qIRwVrp4YAAWBgB0+mRF8sz4+W7sXgD0dcgAglCUbCpgyDIwyGAS8ijhocgGDDKdIvjAlCBw7IIoYDLI8nBQcKwQkFBdPX0DyKHKAG7QoUXWfLz82EKTyJKyCkodAOoyUADW2talYCRwCxBCw5PBwOyOFxkTzeXLIPwgAJBdAhQ4RKKxEAJFLpTKoUH0ArFP7lSrVWrIBrIADyn0uOCuQA)

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the property name as below:

```js
const b = { s: 'asdf', n: 1234 } as a;
```

[Sample Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBMCWDOkF4IG0C6BuAUNAdmEATgGYCGAxiBCRAN6YQOwQBcE8BuA5lgxDi3wCuAWwBGhLAF9MmMgHsc8CKIhIabVgHISsACZFNAGj6sAjACYAzABZJVJiSwx4AOgAOg2AAsAFKICU6EA)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the key names. Interfaces and objects do not rely on the position of the arguments:

```
const list = [];

interface A {
    s: string;
    n: number;
}

const b: A = {s: 'asdf', n: 1234};
list.push(b)
```

I've added missing `const` for the list declaration. Keep in mind that it is a good practice to name types starting with capital letters. This way you can easier distinguish between variables and types/interfaces. There is also an alternative syntax with type `A` declared near the const `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Object Initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) for ways to initialize an object.

Also note, `{ 'asdf',1234 }` **isn't** a **valid** object initialization **syntax** either. Of many ways, there is a short-hand notation for specifying objects that way(ES2015 onwards), but then the short-hand notation requires these to be valid variable identifiers and the key of the object and the name of the variable should be same.

Instead, we could have written...

```ts
const list = [];
interface A {
    s: string;
    n: number;
}

const s = 'asdf';
const n = 1234;

const b: A = { n, s }; //<-- Short-hand property initializer
list.push(b)
```